# opencv: Failed to write core dump

Tags: java, opencv, apache-storm, kryo

I'm developping an object tracking that is supposed to run on storm cluster. I'm using kryo serialization to transmit opencv::Mat between spout and bolt. upon receiving the tuple, the algothim generate this error:

```
   2018-02-28 19:39:23.536 STDERR Thread-2 [INFO] # A fatal error hasbeen detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
   2018-02-28 19:39:23.538 STDERR Thread-2 [INFO] #
   2018-02-28 19:39:23.538 STDERR Thread-2 [INFO] #  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fb163b90ce9, pid=4623, tid=0x00007fb19bafa700
   2018-02-28 19:39:23.538 STDERR Thread-2 [INFO] # 
   2018-02-28 19:39:23.538 STDERR Thread-2 [INFO] # JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_161-b12) (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
   2018-02-28 19:39:23.539 STDERR Thread-2 [INFO] # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.161-b12 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
   2018-02-28 19:39:23.539 STDERR Thread-2 [INFO] # Problematic frame:
   2018-02-28 19:39:23.539 STDERR Thread-2 [INFO] # C  [libopencv_java2413.so+0x37ce9]  Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1delete+0x9
   2018-02-28 19:39:23.539 STDERR Thread-2 [INFO] #
   2018-02-28 19:39:23.540 STDERR Thread-2 [INFO] # Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit$
   2018-02-28 19:39:23.540 STDERR Thread-2 [INFO] #
   2018-02-28 19:39:23.540 STDERR Thread-2 [INFO] # An error report file with more information is saved as:
   2018-02-28 19:39:23.541 STDERR Thread-2 [INFO] # /home/ubuntu/storm1/workers/5ada5016-2885-4ed9-ac11-df7cf9709652/hs_err_pid4623.log
   2018-02-28 19:39:23.544 STDERR Thread-2 [INFO] #
   2018-02-28 19:39:23.544 STDERR Thread-2 [INFO] # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   2018-02-28 19:39:23.545 STDERR Thread-2 [INFO] #   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
   2018-02-28 19:39:23.545 STDERR Thread-2 [INFO] # The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
   2018-02-28 19:39:23.545 STDERR Thread-2 [INFO] # See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
   2018-02-28 19:39:23.546 STDERR Thread-2 [INFO] #
```

Please Could any one help to understand the error? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the Java Runtime Environment (JRE) crashes because of a programming error which can only be fixed by the JRE developers. You can hope that someone else experienced the same issue and filed a bug report and wait until it's fixed or follow the instructions given in the error message and file a bug report yourself:

> If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
>   The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
>   See problematic frame for where to report the bug.

If you never filed one you carefully need to go through the required reading in order to make you effort to report the bug meaningful since it'll probably be ignored if it contains inaccurate descriptions.